# Maze Game - input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Tags: python

```
import random
from random import randint


print("Welcome to Brandon's Maze Game",
  "You have to get 10 shields or find the exit to win",
  "Good Luck :D")


counter = 0
shields = 3
fate = randint(1,2)
direction = input("You have come to a stop, do you want to turn Left(L) or      Right(R)? ")

if direction == "L":
    if fate == 1:
        shields += 3
        counter += 1
        direction = input("You came across a chest, you now have ",shields,  "! What way do you want to go next? Left(L) or Right(R)? ")
    if fate == 2:
        shields -= 1
        counter += 1
        direction = input("Uh oh, you got attacked and lost a shield, you now have ",shields," shields. Do you want to go Left(L) or Right(R)? ")


if direction == "R":
    if fate == 1:
        shields += 3
        counter += 1
        direction = input("You came across a chest, you now have ",shields, "! What way do you want to go next? Left(L) or Right(R)? ")
    if fate == 2:
        shields -= 1
        counter += 1
        direction = input("Uh oh, you got attacked and lost a shield, you now have ",shields," shields. Do you want to go Left(L) or Right(R)? ")

if counter == 10:
        print("Congratulations, you made it to the end with ",shields,"  shields.")
```

I am making a maze game where the user has the option to go Left("L") or Right("R"), then the program makes a choice whether to make the player find a chest or be attacked. When the user finds a chat they get +3 shields, if they are attacked they lose 1 shield.
When I enter "L" or "R" it says: on line 19
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3.
Not sure what's going on as I am only inputting 1 value?,
 Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You *are* giving `input` three arguments (string, int, string). Here's a demo with a function that prints its number of arguments:

```
>>> shields = 42
>>> def foo(*args):
...     print(len(args))
... 
>>> foo('fiz', shields, 'buzz')
3
```

What you want is to give *one* string to `input`:

```
>>> foo('fiz {} buzz'.format(shields))
1
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, I am quite new to python but I will try and work with what you said, thanks. Where does foo and buzz come into this? I am quite confused

Comment: @BrandonFarmiloe when you call the `input` function, you give it three arguments. `input` can take at most one argument. I have chosen short strings for the sake of example instead of copying yours.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` is not like `print()`. The prompt is a single string, so concatenate strings with + (where you have comma).  Note that you have to convert non-strings (like `int`) into a string.

```
print("Congratulations, you made it to the end with " + str(shields) + " shields.")
```

or string formatting:

```
print("Congratulations, you made it to the end with {:d} shields.".format(shields))
```

or use literal string interpolation if you are on Python 3.6

```
print(f"Congratulations, you made it to the end with {shields} shields.")
```

Comment: Did you change ALL your prints?

Comment: you mean inputs :)

Comment: Ah ha, I only did it to the Congratulations one to begin with, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that you had more than on parameter in the input function which unlike print you can not do. This can be solved easily using a plus sign to concatenate the strings together instead of a comma, but to do this you have to convert the int shield to a string by just putting str(shield) to convert it. this is what I have written python 2.7 so you might have to change a few things but it should all be there. I also added .upper() to the if statements so it can take both upper and lower case inputs. ps  for python 3 you will do input() not raw_input(). sorry for writing in 2.7 i am not the good with 3. If you have any question feel free to ask

```
import random
from random import randint


print("Welcome to Brandon's Maze Game",
  "You have to get 10 shields or find the exit to win",
  "Good Luck :D")


counter = 0
shields = 3
fate = randint(1,2)
direction = raw_input("You have come to a stop, do you want to turn Left(L) or Right(R)? ")

if direction.upper() == "L":
    if fate == 1:
        shields += 3
        counter += 1
        direction = raw_input("You came across a chest, you now have "+str(shields)+  "! What way do you want to go next? Left(L) or Right(R)? ")
    if fate == 2:
        shields -= 1
        counter += 1
        direction = raw_input("Uh oh, you got attacked and lost a shield, you now have "+str(shields)+" shields. Do you want to go Left(L) or Right(R)? ")


if direction.upper() == "R":
    if fate == 1:
        shields += 3
        counter += 1
        direction = raw_input("You came across a chest, you now have "+str(shields)+"! What way do you want to go next? Left(L) or Right(R)? ")
    if fate == 2:
        shields -= 1
        counter += 1
        direction = raw_input("Uh oh, you got attacked and lost a shield, you now have "+str(shields)+" shields. Do you want to go Left(L) or Right(R)? ")

if counter == 10:
        print("Congratulations, you made it to the end with "+str(shields)+"  shields.")
```